# "To be indebted to someone" vs "To owe to somebody" [transitive / intransitive]

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I have made two self-made similar sentences to find out where one can use each one of the verbs "indebted" and "owe". For me, they both can be used without any change in the meaning in both of the following sentences, though I doubt about it:

> - You rescued me and I am **indebted** / **owe** to you. [intransitive role]
> - You saved  my life and I am **indebted** / **owe** *my life* to you. [transitive role]

Do you confirm it? If not, then please let me know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *indebted* if you mean that generally you owe the other person something, but to specify a specific thing that you owe, e.g. in your second sentence your life, you should use *owe*.

E.g.

> - You rescued me and I *am indebted to* you.
> - You rescued me and I *owe* you.
> - You saved my life and I *am indebted to* you.
> - You saved my life and I *owe* you my life.